# Methods in one object affect another object JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, object

I currently have an class called cube (which represents a 2x2x2 rubik's cube). Within this class I have the following code which creates an array of cubies (the cubes that make up the rubik's cube) and then initialises them. The up() method is used to rotate the top of the cube clockwise 90 degrees:

```
public class cube {
private static cubie[] cornerCube = new cubie[8];

    public void initialise(){
        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
            cornerCube[i] = new cubie();
            cornerCube[i].setPos(i);
            cornerCube[i].setOrient(0);
        }
    }

    public void up(){
        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
            if(cornerCube[i].getPos()<=3){
                cornerCube[i].setPos((cornerCube[i].getPos()+3)%4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am storing 2 pieces of information about each cubie: the orientation and the position. Below is the code for the cubie class:

```
public class cubie {
    private int orientation;
    private int position;

    public void setOrient(int orient){
        orientation = orient;
    }

    public void setPos(int pos){
        position = pos;
    }

    public int getOrient(){
        return orientation;
    }

    public int getPos(){
        return position;
    }
}
```

The problem appears when I try to execute the following piece of code in the main part of my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    cube cube1 = new cube();
    cube cube2 = new cube();

    cube1.initialise();
    cube2.initialise();
    cube1.up();
    cube1.print();
    System.out.println("...");
    cube2.print();
}
```

I didn't include the print method because it is quite long and I have debugged it thoroughly but what it does is print out the state of the current cube giving the position and orientation of each cubie.

What you would expect is 2 different states, one of which has had the top rotated clockwise, and the other is the initial state of the cube. What I actually get is 2 identical states of the cube BOTH of which have had the top rotated clockwise.

Sorry for the long post, if anyone could shed any light on this problem I would be very grateful.

-T

Comment: Start you class name with a Capital letter. It's just convention and not a necessity.

Comment: Could you add what you expect the output to be and what the actual output is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one `cornerCube` array for the entire `cube` class, because the variable is marked `static`.  Change

```
public class cube {
    private static cubie[] cornerCube = new cubie[8];
```

to

```
public class cube {
    private cubie[] cornerCube = new cubie[8];
```

so you get one array of `cubie`s per instance of `cube`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'm new to Java programming and OOP in general so I'm still a little hazy on these things.